# how to create a symbolic link in Jython

Tags: java, jython, symlink

I'm working on a project that uses Jython 2.2.

Seems like Jython 2.2 doesn't have os.symlink() or anything that can help create a symbolic link.

So I thought to use the Java createSymbolicLink(). But createSymbolicLink() requires a Java data type "Path", which I have no clue about how to import into Jython...

Does anyone have any idea about how to create a symbolic link in Jython (preferably not using shell commands)?

P.S. I tried "createSymbolicLink()" with Java 1.6.0 and it didn't work because somehow Java didn't recognize "Path" even after I did "import java.nio.*"... Any idea...?

Thanks a lot!

Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for symlinks in Java 6. With Java 7 you could (untested):

```
from java.nio.file import FileSystems # requires Java 7 (July 28, 2011)

def mksymlink(target, path):
    """Make a symlink from target to path."""
    fs = FileSystems.getDefault()
    target, path = [fs.getPath('', [name]) for name in [target, path]]
    path.createSymbolicLink(target)
```

Jython 2.5 has `os.symlink()` implemented [using jruby posix module](http://jython.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/jython/test/file/4103b41fdeb5/jython/src/org/python/modules/posix/PosixModule.java#l20).

With Jython 2.2 on Java 6 you might need to call `ln`:

```
import os
from java.lang import Runtime

def mksymlink(target, path):
    path = os.path.abspath(path)
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(["ln", "-s", target, path]);
    process.waitFor();
    process.destroy();
```

To mass produce symlinks you could communicate with external python process:

```
import os
from java.lang import Runtime
from java.io import PrintWriter

class Symlinker:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path)
        self.out = PrintWriter(self.process.getOutputStream())

    def __call__(self, target, path):
        self.out.write("%s\0%s\n" % (target, path))
        self.out.flush()

    def terminate(self):
        self.out.close()
        self.process.waitFor()
        self.process.destroy()

symlinker = Symlinker(["python", "symlinker.py"])

def mksymlink(target, path):
    symlinker(*map(os.path.abspath, [target, path]))
```

Where `symlinker.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys

for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
    target, path = line.rstrip('\n').split('\0')
    os.symlink(target, path)
```

It is a translation to Jython/Python of Java/C implementation from [Creating Symbolic Links with Java at Runtime](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/index.php/2009/01/04/creating-symbolic-links-with-java-at-runtime/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! My environment doesn't support Python at all... So I think I'll just go with your first suggestion! Thanks again! - Jack